# Framework alike jQuery for desktop

Tags: jquery, winforms, desktop

In my winform apps I need to load a page and be able to manipulate html elements, read data, tag and input values to analyze them in program. I wonder if there any framework that would allow be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  and [HtmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class?

Comment: I've read that it is possible to inject jquery to a page and run it in WebBrowser. But I don't understand how can I fetch tags' values and do something with it in my winforms.

Comment: did you look at the example code of htmlelement? it shows how you can use webbrowser.document to fetch html elements from a page

Comment: Now I did. JavaScript allows manipulating DOM, but jQuery makes it easier. Maybe for my purposes it will be enough, thank you.